# Problem detecting https in nodejs and nginx

Tags: node.js, nginx, https

I've seen similar questions around and tried different solutions but none seems to work for me, so I guess I have something wrong in my nginx configurations file.

I have configured nginx to redirect all request to port 8080 except for some locations as I have a nodejs app running on 8080 besides a php application running on port 80 (and another nodejs app service running on 8090) all on the same server (I know it's a weird configuration but I have to live with it for the moment). In my nodejs application I'm tryin to detect if the connection is over http or https but it doesn't work.

I alway get the following regardless I connect over http or https:

```
console.log(req.headers["x-forwarded-proto"]); // => undefined
console.log(req.secure); // => false
```

here is my nginx config file:

```
server {
         listen 80 default_server;
         listen [::]:80 default_server;

         listen 443 ssl;
         ssl_certificate  /etc/nginx/ssl/server.chained.crt;
         ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key;
         ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;

         root /var/www/html;

         index index.html index.htm index.php index.cgi;

         fastcgi_buffers 8 16k;
         fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;

         client_max_body_size 100M;
         client_body_buffer_size 128k;

         server_name factory.quiddis.com;

         location / {
                 proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
                 proxy_http_version 1.1;
                 proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                 proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                 proxy_set_header Host $host;
                 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Ssl on;
                 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                 proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
         }

         location /bugzilla {
                 try_files $uri $uri/ /index.cgi$is_args$args;
         }

         location /bugzilla/rest {
                 rewrite ^/bugzilla/rest/(.*)$ /bugzilla/rest.cgi/$1 last;
         }
...
```

**Note:**

Although I know I could redirect `http` to `https` via nginx, I cannot do it here as the second nodejs app has to stay over http for the moment.

Comment: You do not set a value for `x-forwarded-proto` in the `location` block. You set a value for `X-Forwarded-For`, so is this server behind another reverse proxy?

Comment: `X-Forwarded-For` is copied from an answer I found in one thread but even without it won't work. WHich value due I have to set for `x-forwarded-proto`?

Comment: If there isn't a reverse proxy in front of this server, you need to set using `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;`

Comment: That worked thank'you very much! Now `console.log(req.headers["x-forwarded-proto"]); // => https | http `